# How to write a script that selects bone constraints and fill in the blanks

Tags: scripting, bones, constraints

I am using Blender2.78 and have zero coding knowledge. I'd like to run a script that adds bone constraints 'Copy Location' and 'Copy Rotation' in each bone in my armature and fills in the target slot with the name of the second armature I want to copy from.

I watched a tutorial and have my script like this:

```
import bpy

for bone in bpy.context.object.pose.bones:
    if bone == 'EMPTY':
        bpy.context.object.pose.bones["bone"].constraints["Copy Rotation"].target = bpy.data.objects["Attacker Control"]
```

I click run script but nothing happens. Could someone teach me step by step how to do this? Also, I know what I'm doing sounds like it is solvable by linking animation data. I've tried that but it didn't work, so I've resorted to doing it manually. I'm hoping to speed up the process with this method.

Comment: `if bone.name == 'EMPTY':`